# Wrong ESXi disk size

Tags: mount, hard-drive, esx

Newbie question - our sysadmin added a virtual disk to our Linux server using something called ESXi of which I am not familiar. When I do `fdisk -l` I can see the new disk:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 300 GiB, 322122547200 bytes, 629145600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

But when I do `df -h /dev/sdb` the size is not right:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /dev
```

Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newbie indeed. `df -h /dev/sdb` does not show stats for `sdb` but rather to `/dev`. If

I want to see `df` stats for the new disk I need to:

1. Create a partition.
2. Create file-system.
3. Mount the partion.

```
sudo parted /dev/sdb ext4 0% 100%
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sdb1
```

1. https://linuxhint.com/how-to-mount-drive-in-ubuntu/
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315063/mount-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18925/how-to-mount-a-device-in-linux